# Merge two rows of SQL data from JOIN query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have built the following query that succesfully runs the report i need. However, the `punch_in` and `punch_out` columns are not as i would like.

```
SELECT c.first_name as customer_name, ch.id as clean_home_id, sl.modified_date as punch_in,sl2.modified_date as punch_out, e.first_name as employee_name, ch.employee_id,isnull(chlog.timespent, 0) AS timespent
FROM clean_home_status_log sl
INNER JOIN clean_home ch on sl.clean_home_id = ch.id
INNER JOIN customer c on ch.customer_id = c.id
INNER JOIN employee e on ch.employee_id = e.id
INNER JOIN clean_home_status_log sl2 on sl.id = sl2.id 
Outer APPLY GetCleanHomeKeeperTime(ch.id) chlog
WHERE (sl.new_status = 8 or sl.new_status = 9) and (c.id = 26749) and CONVERT(DATE,sl.modified_date) >= '2017-11-01' order by clean_home_id
```

Produces:

```
Josh    82104   2017-11-01 14:16:21.947 2017-11-01 14:16:21.947 Lupe    1334    1.01
Josh    82104   2017-11-01 15:17:02.303 2017-11-01 15:17:02.303 Lupe    1334    1.01
Josh    82105   2017-11-02 14:23:35.803 2017-11-02 14:23:35.803 Lupe    1334    1
Josh    82105   2017-11-02 15:23:27.233 2017-11-02 15:23:27.233 Lupe    1334    1
```

As you can see it's duplicating each row to show and showing `punch_in` time in the first row and the `punch_out` time in the second row of each result. What i would like is...

```
Josh    82104   2017-11-01 14:16:21.947 2017-11-01 15:17:02.303 Lupe    1334    1.01
```

That shows the `punch_in` and `punch_out` time in the same row

What am i missing?

Comment: can you provide minimum table defs and data so that someone can reproduce your problem. Also, can you cut down your query at all?For instance, do we really need to know about `GetCleanHomeKeeperTime` in order to solve your problem?

Comment: Hello, its complicated to know without knowing the structure of those tables, but I think your mistake is in the join, you have this "on sl.id = sl2.id" and I think you want this "on sl1.clean_home_id = sl2.clean_home_id" or something like that. Motive: A record of table clean_home_status_log is a punch, and you have that table twice. But in the join you are joining with the same record instead of joining with the out record

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: @DeanOC Not really. Yes I think the function is necessary as it’s part of the result.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: As noted, this question can't be answered without information about the tables. In particular the main question is: is there some column in the clean_home_status_log table that can be used to associate the punch-in row with the punch-out row?  If there is, then it will be possible to craft a simple join solution to achieve your result.  If there is not, then a more complex query is required that heuristically tries to match them (for example, by looking for the last punch-in prior to the punch out).

Comment: question, will the cleaners in-date and out-date will always be on the same day or will there be cases that out-date would  be on the next day?

Comment: @JustinAdrias Always same day.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup have you try using CTE separate in and out and and use inner join on date.i will try to form a solution and post it later if i have time. I also encounter this problem few months ago while i was working on a Daily Time Record  Project.

Comment: @JustinAdrias I’m not sure what you mean by that. I know enough  SQL to be dangerous, not necessarily understanding it all. Will look forward to your solution.

Answer (score -1):

With the little information you delivered, here is my try:

```
SELECT 
    c.first_name as customer_name, 
    ch.id as clean_home_id,
    MIN(sl.modified_date) as punch_in,
    MAX(sl2.modified_date) as punch_out,
    e.first_name as employee_name,
    ch.employee_id,
    isnull(chlog.timespent, 0) AS timespent 
FROM clean_home_status_log sl 
INNER JOIN clean_home ch on sl.clean_home_id = ch.id 
INNER JOIN customer c on ch.customer_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN employee e on ch.employee_id = e.id 
INNER JOIN clean_home_status_log sl2 on sl.id = sl2.id 
Outer APPLY GetCleanHomeKeeperTime(ch.id) chlog 
WHERE (sl.new_status = 8 or sl.new_status = 9) and (c.id = 26749) and CONVERT(DATE,sl.modified_date) >= '2017-11-01' 
GROUP BY c.first_name, ch.id, e.first_name, ch.employee_id, isnull(chlog.timespent, 0)
order by clean_home_id
```

Comment: Yeah... I did not see the ORDER BY clause... Just edited the query

Comment: Yea I did that, but this format still complains about customer_name not being part of an aggregate function.

Comment: customer_name is just an alias for c.first_name, so the query should work fine :|